# How do I configure git-lfs to use an Amazon S3 backend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, git-lfs

I'm trying to set up Git LFS to work with an S3 bucket as a backend. I've been trying to follow instructions at [meltingice/git-lfs-s3](https://github.com/meltingice/git-lfs-s3), but I'm having trouble figuring out where to put my AWS credentials and url. At the moment, I have these in my root Git directory:

**.lfsconfig**

```
[lfs]
    url = https://my-aws-folder.amazonaws.com
```

**.config**

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true 
    symlinks = false 
    ignorecase = true 
[remote "origin"] 
    url = https://github.com/my-user-name/test_repo.git 
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

**.env**

```
AWS_REGION=2 
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ABC1234 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=blahblahblah
S3_BUCKET=my-aws-folder 
LFS_SERVER_URL=https://my-aws-folder.s3.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Ahhhh I think I miss understood the function of the *Endpoint* variable that is overwritten by the *url* variable in the *.lfsconfig* file. I thought I could just point it directly at my s3 bucket. Turns our I need to host my own lfs server that can then pass my large files to s3.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note from a few years later, now that meltingice/git-lfs-s3 is archived, I made a similar simple standalone client (no running server needed).

You can find it on [sourcehut](https://git.sr.ht/%7Engraves/lfs-s3) or [github](https://github.com/nicolas-graves/lfs-s3).